# Is there a way to get Sonar to verify that a file exists?

Tags: sonarqube

Something which is a consistent problem in projects I've been working on is a lack of a README (of any form). I'd like to have Sonar verify that either a README file exists in a project root or that a `docs/` folder exists which has at least one file in it.

I haven't seen these options as a Sonar rule.

I am more than willing to write an extension (I have before for other custom rules), but it seems like I would have to have the same check called for every file in the project instead of just once on the project root.

Is there an existing rule to check for a certain file/folder?
If not, is there a way to write an extension to only check for that file/folder once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by David, the [Puppet Plugin](https://github.com/iwarapter/sonar-puppet) provides a rule for README.md, but you appear to have a number of files you want to check. IMO, this is an excellent candidate for custom coding, but I would recommend implementing a *Rule Template*, rather than a straight rule. That way you write the rule once and simply configure the variations in the GUI.

Comment: Is there a way to have the command run only once per-project instead of once-per-file? So far, the hooks I've seen run against every file, and that would mean checking to see if the file/folder exists far more than I'd like.

Comment: The Puppet plugin checks that each Puppet module contains a README file. So, it might help. See https://github.com/iwarapter/sonar-puppet/blob/master/puppet-checks/src/main/java/com/iadams/sonarqube/puppet/checks/ReadmeFilePresentCheck.java and https://github.com/iwarapter/sonar-puppet/blob/master/sonar-puppet-plugin/src/main/java/com/iadams/sonarqube/puppet/checks/ProjectChecks.java#L98